# Towers of Hanoi with "counter" in python

Tags: python, python-2.x, towers-of-hanoi

I have written a code for "Towers of Hanoi" in python and I am trying to add a counter to show how many times it has run. I tried several things like a while loop and for loops etc. but it doesn't work. I am sure that the answer is pretty easy but my brain is running on the lowest setting right now. My code looks like this:

```
def Hanoi(n, src, dst, tmp):
if n > 0:
    Hanoi(n - 1, src, tmp, dst)
    print "Move disc", chr(64 + n), "From tower", src, "to tower", dst
    Hanoi(n - 1, tmp, dst, src)

Hanoi(4,0,2,1) #Just an example
```

I know that the code has to run (2^n)-1 times, but I just cant implement it. Because the way I wrote the code the value n changes so that would work for me. (I tried something like this:

```
def Hanoi(n, src, dst, tmp):

    a = 0
    while (a < (2**n)-1)
        a+=1

    if n > 0:
        Hanoi(n - 1, src, tmp, dst)
        print a, "Move disc", chr(64 + n), "From tower", src, "to tower", dst
        Hanoi(n - 1, tmp, dst, src)
```

but as I've said, the value n changes and I don't know how to fix it.

Edit:

To clarify, I want it to shop the number of steps like this: (If I call Hanoi(3,0,2,1))

```
1. Move disc A From tower 0 to tower 2
2. Move disc B From tower 0 to tower 1
3. Move disc A From tower 2 to tower 1
4. Move disc C From tower 0 to tower 2
5. Move disc A From tower 1 to tower 0
6. Move disc B From tower 1 to tower 2
7. Move disc A From tower 0 to tower 2
```

Comment: Why have the while loop with the "a" variable? If I understand you want a counter to know how many times the function Hanoi() get's called right? If that is the case I can answer the question.

Comment: Yes, I've added a clarification. I added a while loop because I know exaclty how many times the function will run ((2 * * n) - 1). But I want to know exactly how many times it has run while it is running if I decide to run it with a highly value as n (like f.ex. 30)

Answer (score 3):

How about returning the number of calls from your function:

```
def Hanoi(n, src, dst, tmp):
    if n > 0:
        pre = Hanoi(n - 1, src, tmp, dst)
        print "Move disc", chr(64 + n), "From tower", src, "to tower", dst
        post = Hanoi(n - 1, tmp, dst, src)
        return pre + post + 1
    else:
        return 1
```

Note that this counts the number of calls to the `Hanoi` function, not the number of moves that actually need to be made if you were physically playing the game. If you want the number of moves, just change the `return 1` in the base case (the last line) to `return 0`.

Answer (score 2):

There's another solution without using "global". Since not every language has it.

```
count = 0
def Hanoi(count , n , a, c, b):
    if(n == 1):
        print(count,": Moving disk 1 from",a,"to",c)
        count+=1
        return count
    count = Hanoi(count , n-1, a, b, c)
    print(count , ": Moving disk",n,"from",a,"to",c)
    count+=1
    count = Hanoi(count , n-1, b, c, a)
    return count

Hanoi(count , 3, 'A', 'C', 'B')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a global counter to keep track of how many time the function is called.

```
runcount = 0 

def Hanoi(n, src, dst, tmp):

    if n > 0:
        global runcount
        runcount += 1 
        Hanoi(n - 1, src, tmp, dst)
        print "Move disc", chr(64 + n), "From tower", src, "to tower", dst 
        Hanoi(n - 1, tmp, dst, src)

Hanoi(4,0,2,1) #Just an example

print runcount
```

It prints 15 at the end.

Answer (score 0):

1.def hanoi(n,s,t,b):

```
   assert n > 0
    if n == 1:
        print 'move',s,'to',t
        return 1     #######count number of iteration
    else:
        first=hanoi(n-1,s,b,t)
        second=hanoi(1,s,t,b)
        third=hanoi(n-1,b,t,s)
        return first+second+third#####return times of 1
    ###print it on calling
```

for i in range(1,5):

```
    print 'New Hanoi Example: hanoi(',i,',source, target, buffer)'
    print '----------------------'
    print hanoi(i,'source','target','buffer')
```