# python tower of hanoi endless last move

Tags: python

for school we have to make a python script of the tower of hanoi. now this is not really hard and I know how to do this but I wanted to make a step counter in it. and now that i did it like in the code below it does not stop making the last move. this has the result that it overflows the input.

can you guys see whats wrong with it because I can't figure it out?

```
def hanoi(disk, start='START', end='END', middle='MIDDLE'):
    count = 0
    busy = "true"
    while busy == "true":
        if disk > 0:
            hanoi(disk - 1, start, middle, end)
            print('Move disk' + str(disk) + ' from ' + start + ' to ' + end)
            hanoi(disk - 1, middle, end, start)
            count = count + 1
        elif disk == 0:
            busy = "false"


        print (count)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    hanoi(int(input('How many disks you wanna play? ')))
```

after asking here and a bit of help from my teacher I found the problem: the correct code is below:

```
count = 0

def increment():
    global count
    count = count+1

def hanoi(disk, start='START', end='END', middle='MIDDLE'):

    if disk > 0:
        hanoi(disk - 1, start, middle, end)
        print('Move disk' + str(disk) + ' from ' + start + ' to ' + end)
        increment()
        hanoi(disk - 1, middle, end, start)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    hanoi(int(input('How many disks you wanna play? ')))

print (count)
```

thanks for the help you all.

Comment: As a side note, why are you using the strings `"true"` and `"false"` instead of just using the values `True` and `False`? (And then you could just do `while busy:`, too.)

Comment: You can make count  a list `count = [0]`, then   `count[0] += 1`in your function and `print  count[0]` at teh end

Comment: As an aside, a cleaner design would be to have `hanoi` *return* the count, rather than using a global variable. Or alternatively, pass in an extra object to `hanoi` that has an `increment` method. Or even better, have this extra object have a `move` method, and all hanoi does is to invoke `foo.move(disk, start, end)`, and then `move` can do all of the wonderful things you want to do per move, like increment a count (which is stored in `foo`), and/or to print the move to screen. And later when you want to do something else, all you have to do is change the `foo` that gets passed in.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Towers of Hanoi with "counter" in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21876214/towers-of-hanoi-with-counter-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at the function you've written. If you input 7, then `hanoi(7)` is the function that does the following:

1. Set `count = 0`
2. Initialize `busy = True`
3. Invoke a function call that is supposed to say how to move the top 6 disks onto another peg
4. Say how to move the biggest disk
5. Invoke a function call that is supposed to say how to move the top 6 disks onto the biggest disk
6. Increment `count`
7. Print `count` (which will be `1` the first time you reach this step)
8. Go back to step 3

Do you see the problem?

Comment: maybe, is it that before step 7 I need to say the script to only do step 7 when busy = "false"? 

I'm not very good with scripting so forgive me if i don't see